# vswhere fails to detect my visual studio community 2017

Tags: visual-studio

I have version 15.9.28307.344 of Visual Studio Community 2017 installed and running, but vswhere fails to detect it:

```
C:\Users\guivh>"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"
Visual Studio Locator version 2.5.2+gebb9f26a3d [query version 1.18.21.37008]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


C:\Users\guivh>
```

Please advise about what info I should provide to assist in fixing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by installing

1. current flutter (Channel master, v1.10.1-pre.39, on Microsoft
   Windows [Version 10.0.18970.1005], locale nl-BE)
2. latest Visual Studio Community edition 2019

I did have to add the location of vswhere.exe ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer") to my path variable: this is the tool used by flutter to locate the installed Visual Studio and to verify that the required components are installed.